# Где найти непростой эмулятор ESP8266/ESP32 (Arduino) для адресных светодиодов и матриц LED WS2812b?

Tags: arduino, эмулятор, электроника, esp32, схемотехника

Нужен эмулятор ESP8266/ESP32 (Arduino) для работы с умной светодиодной лентой и матрицами типа WS2812b.
Пока нашел только очень простые эмуляторы, которые ограничены использованием либо ленты в одну строку на N светодиодов,
либо квадратными матрицами.
Мне же необходимо расположить в произвольном порядке (в виде определенного рисунка, например большого смайлика)
несколько различных матриц - круглых, квадратных, прямоугольных.

```
 XXX              XXX
XXXXX            XXXXX
 XXX              XXX
        

      XXXXXXXXXX
      XXXXXXXXXX
```

С физическим соединением последовательно для управления с ОДНОГО пина ESP/Arduino (Как будто это одна длинная лента из 200-300 светодиодов, расположенная в виде рисунка) .

Подскажите эмуляторы (Обычные - под Win/Lin) или онлайн, в которых возможно это реализовать (написание кода и визуализацию).

Comment: В эмуляторе можно порезать ленту?

Comment: Пока не нашел такого.

Answer (score 0):

Поскольку эмуляторов Arduino-совместимых плат мало, скорее всего нужного Вам эмулятора не существует. Но Вы могли бы создать схему в эмуляторе с помощью отдельных светодиодов, и матриц (либо лент).

Например, Вам нужен смайлик из Вашего вопроса. Создаете из последовательно подключенных светодиодов (smd) глаза, потом создаете рот из светодиодных лент, после соединяете последовательно глаза и рот. Все это *вроде бы* можно сделать в эмуляторе Wowki.

Если не нужно использовать специфичное API платы, то без разницы какую выбирать плату в эмуляторе. Только не забудьте добавить библиотеку в эмуляторе.

PS: это довольно рутинно, но других решений я не вижу.